# What is MQPUT_REPLY in wireshark traffic capture?

Tags: ibm-mq, wireshark

I am analyzing traffic in IBM MQ using Wireshark. I can see that an `MQPUT` message is sent to MQ, and approximately 118 ms later, an `MQPUT_REPLY` message appears. I couldn't find anything in the IBM MQ documentation about `MQPUT_REPLY`. Could you please advise on what `MQPUT_REPLY` is? Is `MQPUT_REPLY` a response from MQ to the MQPUT message?
[image: wireshark ibm mq capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the MQ traffic over SVRCONN (queue manager) & CLNTCONN (client) channels between an MQ Client application and a queue manager.

Every interaction between either the client or queue manager is done via a Transmission Segment. Every Transmission Segment has a header called TSH (Transmission Segment Header). IBM considers the TSH as proprietary information and does not publish any documentation. Hence, the reason you cannot find any information on it.

Also, the maximum size of any segment is 32768 bytes.

Wireshark understands some or most of the information because people have been reverse-engineering all of the TSH data for years.

The channel between the client and the queue manager has bi-directional communication. When the client application issues an MQPUT API call (message data less than 32KB), the MQ Client library prefixes the TSH to the message data and sends to the queue manager. The queue manager will process the MQ call and reply with a TSH segment of MQPUT_REPLY with information about what happened to the MQPUT, including the Completion Code and Reason Code. If you look carefully, you can see this also happens with the MQCMIT in your screenshot.

If the client application issues an MQPUT API call with message data larger than 32KB, then the MQ Client library will break up the message data into 32KB chunks and send each chunk with a TSH. In the TSH, it will be marked either First, Middle or Last segment. The queue manager will assemble all of the chunks into the original message, process it and then reply with a TSH segment of MQPUT_REPLY.

This communication happens with all MQ API calls. i.e. MQCONN will have a matching MQCONN_REPLY segment, MQOPEN will have a matching MQOPEN_REPLY segment, etc...

Comment: I would add - consider that there are a number of fields on an MQPUT that are output - for example the CompCode and Reason code, the Message ID in the MQMD that shows the message ID that was created by the queue manager - theses are all returned to the application upon completion of the MQPUT call. the MQPUT_REPLY is the flow that delivers all the output fields. You can see all the fields that are output (or input/output in some cases) by reading the IBM Doc about the verb in question.